# JavaScript Video Decoder to Synchronize Frames

Tags: javascript, html, video, synchronization

I am implementing an HTML5 video player that basically consists of multiple tiles, implemented as canvases. I am trying to find a way in which I can decode a H.264 video to control how each frame is displayed in a synchronized manner. 
Meaning that when one video is displayed across the multiple canvases I would want all of the tiles to display the same frame at the same time. So to control this synchronized display I would like any ideas as to how I could implement this, using JavaScript for instance.

Help will be appreciated!

Thanks!